# Vector bundle definition, what topology?

Tags: definition, vector-bundles

I've read the following definition of a vector bundle.

---

A rank $n$ vector bundle on a manifold $M$ is a map $\pi:V\to M$, where for each point $x\in M$, the fibre $\pi^{-1}(x)$ is endowed with the structure of an $n$-dimensional vector space. Each point $x\in M$ has a neighbourhood $U$ such that $\pi^{-1}(U)$ is homeomorphic to $U\times \Bbb R^n$, such that the diagram given by $\pi^{-1}(U)\to U$ and $\pi^{-1}(U)\to U\times \Bbb R^n \stackrel{p_1}\to U$ is commutative. Additionally the homeomorphism must restrict to fibres and give vector space isomorphisms $\pi^{-1}(x)\to \{x\}\times \Bbb R^n$.

---

Now, in this definition, we say that $U\times \Bbb R^n$ is homeomorphic to $\pi^{-1}(U)$. Are we endowing $U\times \Bbb R^n$ with the product topology? Are we endowing the total space $V$ with the topology that this is inducing? What structure does $V$ have thus?

Comment: The topology on $U \times \mathbb{R}^n$ is the product topology. If one knows the transition maps between the different neighborhoods $U$, one may reconstruct the topology on $V$, although this is not so easy.

Comment: The topology of V is given.

Comment: The beginning of the definition should say that $V$ is a topological space and $\pi$ is continuous. Perhaps your source takes care of this implicitly, by a convention that "map" means "continuous function between topological spaces".  $U\times\mathbb R^n$ is to be understood as having the product topology.  It turns out that a subset $G$ of $V$ is open in $V$ iff, for each of the neighborhoods $U$ under discussion, $\pi(G\cap(\pi^{-1}(U)))$ is open in $U\times\mathbb R^n$.